Reference variable in Store.swift class from Objective-C file using singleton pattern giving Linker command failed error
I am trying to reference a variable in a Swift class from an Objective-C view controller.
I can reference functions and variables in other Swift Classes from this Objective-C class. However, when I try to reference variables in this class in particular, which is a Store class containing Storekit2 when I try to build, it generates two errors:
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC5myapp5Store
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
 

I believe the issue has something to do with Objective-C not being able to see every type of Swift Class. It can see classes with which it is familiar such as UIView Controllers but not new ones such as the Store.
Here is the beginning of the Store file in Swift (which has all the Storekit functions. I think the Store_from_Objc was an unfinished effort to make the class observable from Swift but the documentation done by a previous programmer does not go into any detail.
//Store.swift
import StoreKit

//CLASS STUB FOR TESTING ObjC
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
@objcMembers public class Store_from_Objc: NSObject,ObservableObject {
    static var shared = Store_from_Objc()
    @objc var teststring1 = "hello from store_from_objc class"
    public func initAndLoad () {
        Store.shared.initAndLoad()
    } 
}
//FULL CLASS WITH METHODS FOR STORE
        @objcMembers public class Store: NSObject, ObservableObject {       
            typealias Transaction = StoreKit.Transaction
            typealias RenewalInfo = StoreKit.Product.SubscriptionInfo.RenewalInfo
            typealias RenewalState = StoreKit.Product.SubscriptionInfo.RenewalState
            
            static var shared = Store()
        @objc var testing2 = "hello from actual Store"
        //LOTS MORE CODE
}

Here is the Obj-c file from which I'm trying to reach Swift variable.
//import bridging header so that obj-c file knows about swift files

    #import "myapp-Swift.h"
   if (@available(iOS 15.0, *)) {
    NSString *test1 = [Store_from_Objc shared].teststring1;
    NSString *test2 = [Store shared].teststring2;
    NSLog(@"%@",test1);
    NSLog(@"%@",test2);
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}

The code does not generate an error when written but throws the two above errors when you try to build referencing the NSString in the Store class. The project builds ok if you just try to reference the Store_from_Objc variable.
These errors go away if you comment out the attempt to reach the Store class variables.
I did come across a line in an article that says "Using StoreKit 2 is not possible with Objective-C". My storekit code is all in Swift but it would be nice to reach variables in the Store class.
Thanks for any suggestions.
Edit
Playing around with this some more, I can reach a string variable if I put it in the Store_from_objc class but cannot reach the string if I put it in regular Store class even with the @available(iOS 15.0, *) as suggested by Larme.  The Store_from_objc class inherits from the same objects but doesn't contain any substantive code....
Could the Storekit2 methods be causing the errors?  Thanks for any suggestions.

I tried and it compiled. I just had to add @available(iOS 15.0, *) above  @objcMembers public class Store:...

I was able to access a variable in Store_from_Objc from is just a stub of.a class but not in the full class Store.  The code included above is just the beginning of the Store class. The actual one has hundreds of lines of code...It could be that some of the StoreKit2 methods may be the problem although that doesn't make that much sense since both the long version and the short version inherit from (NSObject, ObservableObject)

Maybe you can clarify if the anonymous edit was done by you or someone else. If not please roll back.
